# SSRS prompting for credentials HTTPS but not HTTP

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2017

I have an SSRS 2017 install that does not prompt for credentials when going to the HTTP URL for a report. When I change the URL to HTTPS, regardless of the browser or user, credentials are required/prompted for. How can this be bypassed??

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it for me....

1. Hit Windows key + S key and type Internet Options to bring up Internet Options, got to Security tab
2. Click Sites and confirm that https://*.*domainhere*.*com* is listed
3. Click Custom level and scroll to the bottom for User Authentication and choose Automatic logon with current user name and password
4. close Microsoft Edge, reopen and attempt to go to your SSRS https sites

I don’t know if this will break anything else you connect to in Edge that’s trusted, so please be aware of that